# double level aggregation pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am having some issues using `groupby`. I need to aggregate by one field, but the other field has to be the maximum of all the values for each group. Then I need the sum of this latest aggregation.

Let's say I have this table:

```
field 1 field 2 value
   1       1      0
   1       2      1
   1       3      1
   2       1      1
   2       1      1
   2       4      0
```

I want to know the field 1 count distinct for each field 2 but also the number of `value = 1` for each field 1 (but only counting once each field 2).

```
field 2    count distinct field 1      value = 1
   1                2                     1(because field 1 is the same when value = 1)
   2                1                     1
   3                1                     1
   4                1                     0
```

The way I got it to work is by aggregating twice:

```
df = df.groupby([field1, field2]).aggregate({'value':'max'})
df = df.groupby(field2).aggregate({field1: 'count', 'value': 'sum'})
```

But it takes long time. I am sure there is a lambda function I can use, but I am new to this and I cannot figure it out. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: what do you mean by "it took a long time"?

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your answer. It took 22 seconds (it is a 7Million table). But doing only 1 level aggregation it takes less than 2 seconds.

Comment: Be a little more specific. If you mean that your first groupby operation on 7 million rows took 22 seconds, but then the second operation on the smaller set of results only took 2 seconds, I'd be pretty happy about that.